# Resizing window not working properly MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have created a customized class with inheriting CDockablepane in SDI application MFC. for ex.

```
class CLoginPage :  public CDockablePane
{
    public:
    CLoginPage();
protected:
    CStatic lbl_username;
    CStatic lbl_password;
    CEdit txt_username;
    CEdit txt_password;
    CButton btn_login;
    CButton btn_Signup;
protected:
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

in .cpp I override oncreate function and onsize funtion

```
int CLoginPage::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    if(!lbl_username.Create(_T("User Name"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(150, 150, 100, 30), this, ID_STATIC_USERNAME))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create userName in LoginPage window\n");
        return -1;
    }
 ......................................same for other control
}


void CLoginPage::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDockablePane::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    // Tab control should cover the whole client area:
    CRect rectClient;
    this->GetWindowRect(rectClient);

    lbl_username.SetWindowPos (NULL, rectClient.left+150, rectClient.top+150, 100, 30, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
.............................same for other control
}
```

when I run this it is displaying correctly as present in below image.

[image]

but after resize login window or move login window, it display very badly. please see below image

[image]

I don't know how to resolve this. Do I need to do something in WM_PAINT message or something else. I tried a lot but i din't get any option.
Can someone please help me on this??

Comment: Not immediately clear, why you specify values for *X* and *Y* in your call to `SetWindowPos` even though you are telling the system, that it should ignore those values (`SWP_NOMOVE`). Anyway, your issue is one of these: `1` Your `WM_PAINT` message handler is buggy. `2` Your `WM_ERASEBKGND` message handler is inappropriate. `3` Your window class registration is missing the `CS_HREDRAW`/`CS_VREDRAW` [window class styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176.aspx). In other words: It's in the code we cannot see. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I Have not handled WM_PAINT or WM_ERASEBKGND messages. How I called this Login window is present below: CString strLoginPageWnd;
 bNameValid = strLoginPageWnd.LoadString(IDS_LOGINPAGE_WND);
 ASSERT(bNameValid);

 if (!m_wndLoginPage.Create(strLoginPageWnd, this, CRect(0, 0, 200, 200), TRUE, ID_VIEW_LOGINPAGEWND, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | CBRS_TOP | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
 {
  TRACE0("Failed to create LoginPage window\n");
  return FALSE; // failed to create
 }m_wndLoginPage.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
 DockPane(&m_wndLoginPage);

Comment: Where did you read, that you can mix window styles with class styles? `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW` can only be used when registering a window class.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change position but why do you pass SWP_NOMOVE into SetWindowPos?

Do you know that in Visual Studio 2015 you have possibility to manage dialog layout with dynamic layouts: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270148.aspx ? The best dynamic layouts tutorial is http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2015/07/27/dynamic-dialog-layout-for-mfc-in-visual-c-2015/

Comment: I want to change the position of dockwindow not control placed in Dockwindow. So for control I used SWP_NOMOVE.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the MFC drawing problem -- stuttering lines when moving or sizing a tool window or tool bar was a Windows bug and only occurred with multiple monitors.  It was fixed in Windows 10 1803 but reintroduced in 1809 and fixed in March, 2020 in 1903 and 1909.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4541335/windows-10-update-kb4541335

The description in the KB article (must expand collapsed links):

*Addresses a drawing issue with the Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) toolbar that occurs when dragging in a multi-monitor environment.*